# BL and CM are medians of a triangle ABC right angled at A. Prove that $ 4(BL^2 +CM^2 )=5BC^2 $

Tags: median

BL and CM are medians of a triangle ABC right angled at A. Prove that $ 4(BL^2  +CM^2  )=5BC^2 $

My attempt: I have found out till $ 4BL^2 =4AB^2  +(AC)^2 $. I am not getting how to move forward. Any help will be appreciated.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this https://www.toppr.com/ask/en-in/question/bl-and-cm-are-medians-of-a-triangle-abc-right-angled-at-a-prove-that/ answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have found $4BL^2 = 4AB^2 + AC^2$. Similarly we would have $4CM^2 = 4AC^2 + AB^2$.

Adding them together, we have:

$$4(BL^2 + CM^2) = 4AB^2 + AC^2 + 4AC^2 + AB^2 = 5(AB^2 + AC^2) = 5BC^2$$

The final equality is due to another application of the Pythagorean Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Both $BL$ and $CM$ are medians, so use [Apollonius's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20geometry%2C%20Apollonius%27s%20theorem%20is,median%20bisecting%20the%20third%20side%22.) twice.
$$2AB^2+2BC^2=4BL^2+AC^2$$
$$2BC^2+2AC^2=4CM^2+AB^2$$
Add the two equations and use the fact that (from Pyhtagorean Theorem),
$$AB^2+AC^2=BC^2$$
to finally show that,
$$4(BL^2  +CM^2  )=5BC^2.$$